# Translation of “encato”

Tags: traducción

What does the word `encato` really mean? I have been looking for this word in several dictionaries but was unable to find anything so far.

Examples of usage:

> Excelente, me encato!
>
> A mi hija le encato no se queria salir.

Comment: There's a typo. Me enca**n**t**ó**. And the second sentence does not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*Encato*" is not a word in Spanish. What makes sense for the context you are providing is that there is a typo and the word is "enca**n**to", with an "n". That would explain why you haven't been able to find it in the dictionary.

In the context you provided `encanto` could be traduced as "left me really **pleased**" but the proper meaning would be "*charmed*". Is as if you were saying "I'm so pleased that is as if I was charmed".

If you say that somebody "es un encanto" you are saying the he or she "is a *doll*". Is some sort of flattery term. You convey that their good manners, or pampering or whatever (actually, their *charm*) was charming you.

> A mi hija le encantó. No se quería salir.

Means, "my daughter was so **delighted** that she didn't want to leave".

> Estoy encantado de presentarle al Sr. Pérez

Means, "I'm glad to introduce to you Mr. Pérez".